# Unity get root canvas gameobject from its child

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, canvas

I wanted to get data available in root canvas from the child/member of the canvas. It's possible to do it using this https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Canvas-rootCanvas.html but it is unusable if `this.gameobject` does not have canvas component and adding canvas component is out of option , and manually assign the gameobject from unity editor is also out of option because it close the door for automation.

So my question is , how do i get the root canvas gameobject from its child without using `this.gameObject.GetComponent<Canvas>().rootcanvas` ? I also have tried `collider.transform.root` but it fails if the root canvas is not in the top hierarchy.

Comment: I think your question might be based on a false assumption. It isn't possible to have visible UI that isn't ultimately underneath a Canvas. If you do have a UI object that doesn't have a root canvas, it won't be visible.

Comment: @Joseph yes but to find the root canvas of the UI object , i need to use this.gameObject.GetComponent<Canvas>().rootcanvas , and if my gameobject does not have canvas component , i can't find the root canvas using the canvas.rootcanvas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `GetComponentInParent<Canvas>().rootCanvas`. This assumes you have a valid, visible UI element. Any UI element you can see must have a Canvas higher up in its hierarchy, and then you can get the rootCanvas of *that* canvas.

Comment: okk thankss sorry i'm beginner at unity and i totally forgot about this existence. It's kinda annoying not being able to directly find root canvas from ui member without canvas component. This works but kinda slow in performance if the object was 1000+ object down in hierarcy from the nearest parent with canvas component

Comment: If you are worried about the search being slow, a solution would be to add a reference to the parent canvas at the time the UI element is created, if you know it. Also, you should know that the `.rootCanvas` property is just a shortcut for doing a recursive GetComponentInParent call, so there's not much choice if you don't capture these references ahead of time.

Comment: thanks for helping me at this , in case you're interested , can you please help me here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63482810/detect-hierarchy-change-during-runtime , it's about the performance heavy