# detect hierarchy change during runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, hierarchy

I have a script attached to an UI gameobject that find and get reference to the canvas root gameobject. Right now i keep refreshing the reference every `update()` in case the gameobject is moved to other place in hierarchy and the canvas root changed .

But i found it performance heavy for my script to keep running `GetComponentInParent<Canvas>().rootCanvas` every single `update()` especially when the object is at the bottom of a hierarchy with 1000+ gameobject. So i want my script to only find root canvas at `start()` and when the object hierarchy changed.

I've found https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication-hierarchyChanged.html but it is editor-only and won't follow after build. Is there any way to do something similar to `OnHierarchyChanged()` ? Also using loop to check the current state of hierarchy is out of option .

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:

1. First one, `GetComponentInParent<Canvas>` is expensive, but what
   about simply call `Transform.parent`? You only need to instantiate
   parent reference at the begining, and even if you check it on
   `Update`, is less expensive.
2. Second one, if you know (and you should know) which are the events
   that changes your hierarchy, you can create your own delegate,
   event, action whatever to track it.
3. And finally, I'm not sure about this one, but have you checked
   [Transform.hasChanged](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-hasChanged.html)? I think this last one won't work, cause
   only affect rotation, position etc...but I can't assure it right
   now.

To exemplify Idea 2 (I think the other 2 are pretty clear):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ClassThatCanChangeHierarchy : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<GameObject> objectsThatWantToKnow = new List<GameObject>();

    private void MethodThatChangeHierarchy()
    {
        //your code that affects hierarchy...
        foreach(GameObject go in objectsThatWantToKnow)
        {
            go.GetComponent<ClassThatWantsToKnowWhenHierarchyChanges>().OnHierarchyChange?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}

using UnityEngine;    
using System;

public class ClassThatWantsToKnowWhenHierarchyChanges : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Action OnHierarchyChange = null;

    private void Awake()
    {
        OnHierarchyChange = () => Debug.log("hierarchy has changed");
    }
}
```

Comment: To use rootcanvas , it must refer to canvas that's attached to a gameobject , and using Transform.parent is out of option because if the first parent doesn't have canvas component , i can't use Canvas.rootcanvas. 3rd ideas i can't tell because my object is a child of a canvas and it's transform value is driven by canvas which causes Transform.hasChanged everytime gui is rendered , which is almost as frequent as update().

and your 2nd ideas , i can track it if i change hierarchy from script , but what if unity itself that change hierarchy ? any solution to this ?

Comment: but thanks for at least trying to help me , i upvoted this .

Comment: Thanks for upvote. First option (Transform.parent one) is not restricted to Canvas.rootcanvas. You need a reference to parent GameObject, It doesn't matter if it's not a Canvas. Explain in which scenario Unity itself change hierarchy please, so I can think a solution ^^

Comment: Then how am i going to detect hierarchy change if the first parent is remain the same but hierarchy above it is changed ?

Comment: Cause it's recursive, The parent of your parent has also a reference. Not the fanciest solution, I know, but It world,  the good one should be second solution .

Comment: So i loop parent after parent , the whole hierarchy , to see if it changed ?

Comment: There is no direct loop, cause every object will check only it's direct parent, and if one changes, inform the controller that hierarchy changes.

Comment: Anyway, and as a side note, you don't want to rely on hierarchy to perform stuff, you should avoid It (even more if you have to control hierarchy of hundreds of elements)

Comment: My script is more into adaptability instead of relying on hierarchy , i wanted my script to behave depends on where it's located , that's why i need to detect the hierarchy change. I think adding script to every single object to check whether it hierarchy change is just a parallel version of looping through the whole hierarchy , the difference is too small i think.

Comment: i guess i will remain stick to GetComponentInParent<Canvas>() and letting it to take away 0.2% of my precious resource until a solution is found.